# Javascript variable set to a string

Tags: javascript

Why does my `this.pPos` is set to a string containing the function code, instead of the function return value?

http://jsfiddle.net/SpGwL/

```
function game(mode, boardDim) {
    //mod
    this.mode = mode;
    //dim tabla
    this.boardDim = boardDim;
    //pozitii initiale elemente
    if (this.mode == 'easy') {
        //creez pozitii specifice   
        this.pPos = function () {
            var pPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(this.boardDim, 2));
            return pPos;
        };


    }

}

var asd = new game('easy');
alert(asd.pPos);
```

This should return a random number, but it returns the function's text.

Comment: Because you're not calling the function, `asd.pPos()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to **call** the function.

```
alert(asd.pPos());
```

Alerting the function itself will implicitly call `toString()` on it.

Comment: +1, it's not text. It's just that Javascript gives you the function's code when you attempt to turn it into a string, like `alert()` does.

Comment: I need to wait 10 minutes.